# Book on advanced Hodge Theory

Tags: differential-geometry, book-recommendation, hodge-theory

I'm looking for a book on advanced real Hodge Theory. I finished working through Frank Warner's Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups, which ends with the Hodge Decomposition,the Hodge theorem(stating that the space of harmonic p-forms is isomorphic to the p-th Cohomology Group)as well as formulating(and proofing) the Poincare Duality. Is there any book that covers this topic further?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Try : Voisin, Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry 1&2.

Answer (score 3):

There are too many sources of different flavors to list. If you want to start learning some differential geometry, Goldberg's *Curvature and Homology* is a cheap Dover book with all sorts of results with the interplay of Hodge theory and Riemannian and complex geometry.

Comment: How far in depth does that book go? I'm familiar with Pr. Lee's three books on Manifolds as well as Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry, would there be much overlap?

Comment: "Familiar with"? Do you know Riemannian geometry well? Goldberg gives a lot on the Hodge theory and its connections with the topology and more subtle things in the complex manifold case. Do you know about Bochner's theorems relating topology and curvature?

Comment: I took courses that covered Riemannian geometry up to and including the Cartan–Hadamard theorem(following Lee's book on the subject, basically covering the 4 "big" theorems) and I recently finished working through most of the exercises in Do Carmo(At least the ones that seemed fun). I'm not familiar with Bochner's theorem in relation to curvature, though I seem to remember it somewhat darkly in relation to Fourier transforms. In general I'm not very familiar with the complex case, somehow that never "tickled my fancy".

Comment: Well, I find your post totally misleading. Warner is more elementary than all this stuff. Be straightforward about statin what you've actually studied and learned ... and what specific things interest you.

Comment: I'm sorry if you got the impression that I'm trying to mislead you. I took classes in those subjects and started working through additional material on my own. Warner however(maybe I'm mistaken or just not able to connect the dots) covers, in his last chapter something the other books did not cover, mainly the study of manifolds, especially differential forms(and therefore their cohomology) with the help of functional analysis(my other passion) and more precisely the theory of partial differential equations.